# To check the old dates present or not

Tags: sql-server

I have list of dates like `19/2/2017, 20/8/1975, 02/03/1989, 04/08/2015` . I need a query by using SQL server to find year which is less than current year.

eg: `19/2/2017, 20/8/1975, 02/03/1989`

by using the query, it should display these two `20/8/1975, 02/03/1989`

Comment: Are your dates stored as varchar then, or as datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YEAR(DateFiled) < YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee you convert the dates correctly, *independently* of the SQL Server @@DATEFORMAT

```
DECLARE @BadDateStorage table (BadData varchar(12));

INSERT @BadDateStorage (BadData)
VALUES ('02/03/1989'), ('20/8/1975'), ('019/2/2017');

SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, BadData, 103) 
FROM @BadDateStorage 
WHERE CONVERT(smalldatetime, BadData, 103) < '20170101'
```